# Export Gift Aid?

Tags: custom-fields, export

We have a gift aid tab as show on the attached image.

I can search using the fields using the advanced search function but cannot export the data held in the gift aid fields.

Is there a way I can do this?

Many thanks,
Andy

Drupal, CIVI 4.5.8  [image: Picture of Gift Aid Tab]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try Constituent Summary report where you can set the filters to select all the "UK Tax Payer? **is equal to** yes"

This will give you all the list and you have an option of exporting to CSV or PDF

Comment: If  you want to be able to list all the Gift Aid fields you will need to set them to searchable in the custom fields.